# How do I open multiple ports publicly in a ECS cluster/service/task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have a Docker container that has top public ports 2113 and 1113.  When I created the container in AWS, I opened those ports.

[image]

I am running the container in a task inside of a cluster, but I am only able to access the first port 2113.  I made sure that the ports were open in the security group, but am reading that it is impossible to have more than one port open in an ECS instance.  Is there a way to do this?  Can this container have multiple open ports?

Comment: It's definitely not impossible to have multiple ports open. I've got ECS instances with dynamic port mapping turned on and multiple ports open. Mine are private, and I'm only exposing them to the internet via an ELB, but I can definitely tunnel into the VPC and then see those ports from another machine, so I don't doubt that you could open those up on an Elastic IP Address as well.  Do you have SSH access to any machine in the VPC? Can you check those ports from inside your VPC? Or from one of the ECS instances?

Comment: @jhamm I'm in same trouble. How did you solve it?

Comment: this is possible, using multiple target groups now, I believe

Comment: Add an answer so I can accept